# for loop for files containing specific characters ("rem_trim") in the file name

Tags: shell-script, bioinformatics

I would like to do a for loop on the files below, but only for the files containing "**rem_trim**" in the name. The ones with just trim have been done.

This worked for the files having trim but not rem_trim

```
list=`for i in *trim*.1.fq; do echo $i | cut -f 1 -d \. | uniq ; done`
for i in $list; do fastqc $i.1.fq ; fastqc $i.2.fq; done
```

So this is what I've been trying to do the "rem_trim" files:

```
list=`for i in *rem_trim*.1.fq; do echo $i | cut -f 1 -d \. | uniq ; done`
for i in $list; do fastqc $i.1.fq ; fastqc $i.2.fq; done
```

FIles:

```
sample_AACCA.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_ACTGG_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_CTGCG_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_GCATG_trim.2.fq           sample_GGTTG_trim.1.fq           sample_TCACG.rem_trim.2.fq
sample_AACCA.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_ACTGG_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_CTGCG_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_GCCGT.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_GGTTG_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_TCACG_trim.1_fastqc.html
sample_AACCA_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_ACTGG_trim.2.fq           sample_CTGCG_trim.1.fq           sample_GCCGT.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_GGTTG_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_TCACG_trim.1_fastqc.zip
sample_AACCA_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_CGAAT.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_CTGCG_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_GCCGT_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_GGTTG_trim.2.fq           sample_TCACG_trim.1.fq
sample_AACCA_trim.1.fq           sample_CGAAT.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_CTGCG_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_GCCGT_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_GTCCG.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_TCACG_trim.2_fastqc.html
sample_AACCA_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_CGAAT_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_CTGCG_trim.2.fq           sample_GCCGT_trim.1.fq           sample_GTCCG.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_TCACG_trim.2_fastqc.zip
sample_AACCA_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_CGAAT_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_GCATG.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_GCCGT_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_GTCCG_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_TCACG_trim.2.fq
sample_AACCA_trim.2.fq           sample_CGAAT_trim.1.fq           sample_GCATG.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_GCCGT_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_GTCCG_trim.1_fastqc.zip   SE
sample_ACTGG.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_CGAAT_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_GCATG_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_GCCGT_trim.2.fq           sample_GTCCG_trim.1.fq
sample_ACTGG.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_CGAAT_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_GCATG_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_GGTTG.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_GTCCG_trim.2_fastqc.html
sample_ACTGG_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_CGAAT_trim.2.fq           sample_GCATG_trim.1.fq           sample_GGTTG.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_GTCCG_trim.2_fastqc.zip
sample_ACTGG_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_CTGCG.rem_trim.1.fq       sample_GCATG_trim.2_fastqc.html  sample_GGTTG_trim.1_fastqc.html  sample_GTCCG_trim.2.fq
sample_ACTGG_trim.1.fq           sample_CTGCG.rem_trim.2.fq       sample_GCATG_trim.2_fastqc.zip   sample_GGTTG_trim.1_fastqc.zip   sample_TCACG.rem_trim.1.fq
```

but I get this:

```
Skipping 'sample_AACCA.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_AACCA.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_ACTGG.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_ACTGG.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_CGAAT.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_CGAAT.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_CTGCG.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_CTGCG.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GCATG.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GCATG.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GCCGT.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GCCGT.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GGTTG.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GGTTG.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GTCCG.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_GTCCG.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_TCACG.1.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'sample_TCACG.2.fq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and what may work? thanks!

Comment: what you have posted under `Files` - is that expected output?

Comment: the expected output are the html and zip files. There are ouput files for all the trim files but i'd like to run the loop on the "rem_trim" files

Comment: `cut -d \.` probably does not what you expect.

Comment: I do not understand your problem. You show what you have been trying but do not say anything about what happened (in contrast to what you expected). In addition `for i in *trim*.1.fq` includes all files from `for i in *rem_trim*.1.fq` so the second run doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: I tried only `*rem*` but that didint work.I was wondering why *trim* didn't include all rem_trim files. It has to be the `-d` flag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the first group of files have just one dot in their name, the second group have three.

```
for i in *rem_trim*.1.fq; do echo "${i%.?.fq}" | uniq ; done
```

gives you the right name parts.

But I do not understand why you do not do it much easier:

```
for i in *rem_trim*.1.fq; do
    fastqc $i
done
for i in *rem_trim*.2.fq; do
    fastqc $i
done
```

or even

```
for i in *rem_trim*.1.fq *rem_trim*.2.fq; do
    fastqc "$i"
done
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! And the reason I was doing it the more complicated way is because I'm a rookie that was trying to reverse engineer a different loop that had worked for a different example. I guess you don't need to make the list, thanks!